# Finding pair of files in a folder

Tags: matlab, file

I have a folder with tens of thousand of files. Every file in the folder should have a pair matching except the initial few letter, for example:

```
X_Date_Time_Place.dat
Y_Date_Time_Place.dat
```

Each `X_*` and `Y_*` combine to make one pair of files.

However, there always be some thousand of files extra which need to be eliminated from the folder. The extra files are also of the same type but without pair. For example, there may be more `'X_Date_Time_Place.dat'` then `'Y_Date_Time_Place.dat'`. Only variables in the file names are `'Date'`, `'Time'` and `'Place'`.

I have written a simple script (using for loop) that takes the name of one file and check all the other files in a loop until it finds its match. However, it is taking enormous amount of time to find a pair.

Is there any faster and more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Can you please provide a more detailed explanation of what files exist that you don't want to match. It's not really clear what you want to match and what you want to exclude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split to two lists:

```
xlist = dir( fullfile( path_to_folder, 'X_*.dat') );
ylist = dir( fullfile( path_to_folder, 'Y_*.dat') );
%// remove prefixes
xlist = cellfun(@(x) x(3:end), {xlist.name}, 'uni', false);
ylist = cellfun(@(y) y(3:end), {ylist.name}, 'uni', false);
common = intersect(xlist, ylist);
```

Using [`intersect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html) to find the common suffixes leaves you with `common` holding all `Date_Time_Place.dat` for which you have *BOTH* `X_Date_Time_Place.dat` and `Y_Date_Time_Place.dat`.

To get all pairs:

```
allParis = cellfun(@(c) {fullfile(path_to_folder,['X_',c]), 
                         fullfile(path_to_folder,['Y_',c])}, common, 'uni', false);
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot. Only one more thing. After retrieving all matching file names, I am using copy command to retrieve all pairs. But again I am using 'copyfile' in a for loop. Is it the only way to do it or I can do it in a more compact way.

Comment: @Mushi if you are only copying specific files and cannot use wildcard characters I'm afraid loop is the only option. You might consider `parfor` or other parallel mechanism, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [dir](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) and specify a string and/or an extension that you want your filename to contain :

In your example :

```
I=dir('* _Date_Time_Place *.dat')
```

Will return a `struct` `I` whose fields will be all the filenames containing the string `*_Date_Time_Place*` and having the extension `.dat` .

You can then access to the elements in the struct with calls to `I(1)`, `I(2)`.

### Minor note :

For this to work, your current folder must be the one where your files are.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the extra files are also of the same type but without pair. For example, there may be more 'X_Date_Time_Place.dat' then 'Y_Date_Time_Place.dat'. Only variables in the file names are 'Date', 'Time' and 'Place'.

Comment: I assumed you were seraching for a given pair (by of course replacing 'Date_Time_Place' by an actual value). Do you want the code to extract ALL pairs?

Comment: Yes, please, if possible. I am sorry if I could not understood your answer fully. But, the problem is that, I have already tried dir and could not find a different way forward. I will be grateful If you could give me an example.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't have 10,000 files formatted like this but here is what I would do.

```
Xfiles = dir('X*.dat');
filenames = {Xfiles.name};
% Here I would determine how many pairs I am looking for (the unique X's)
% I am assuming that your X files are unique.
% remove the "X" from the file name
filenames2 = cellfun(@(x) repexprep(x, 'X',''));
keys = filenames2;
values = 1:length(filenames2);
fileMap = containers.Map(keys, values);
% for each Y look for the filename
Yfiles = dir('Y*.dat');
Yfiles2 = cellfun(@(x) repexprep(x, 'Y',''));
pairs = cell(length(Yfiles2),2);
% this assumes that for every Y there must be an X
% if this is not true then handle the empty idx case.
for x = 1:length(Yfiles2)
    idx = fileMap(Yfiles2{x});
    pairs(x,:) = {Xfiles(idx), Yfiles(idx)};
end
```